# Extending EventTarget in TypeScript (Angular 2+) when compiling to ES5

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, es6-class

Is there a way to actually create a class, which will extend the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) DOM API class?

Consider, I'm having this class:

```
class MyClass extends EventTarget {        

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  private triggerEvent() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('someEvent'));
  }

}
```

When I'm trying to instantiate it, I'm getting this error:

- `ERROR TypeError: Failed to construct 'EventTarget': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

Looks like this is due to the fact, that this API requires proper ES2015 classes in order to work, but I'm transpiling my code down to ES5 level.

If I use a constructor like this:

```
constructor() {
  Reflect.construct(EventTarget, [], MyClass);
}
```

I'm getting the following error, when trying to invoke `addEventListener()` on the instance:

- `ERROR TypeError: Illegal invocation`.

As a side effect, I'm also getting this TypeScript compilation error:

- `error TS2377: Constructors for derived classes must contain a 'super' call.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most simple solution would be to actually implement the `EventTarget` interface, but to delegate the actual implementation to some existing class, like `DocumentFragment`.

Also, we could extract this functionality to the reusable class:

```
export class DelegatedEventTarget implements EventTarget {

  private delegate = document.createDocumentFragment();


  addEventListener(...args: any): void {
    this.delegate.addEventListener.apply(this.delegate, args);
  }

  dispatchEvent(...args: any): boolean {
    return this.delegate.dispatchEvent.apply(this.delegate, args);
  }

  removeEventListener(...args: any): void {
    return this.delegate.removeEventListener.apply(this.delegate, args);
  }

}
```

Then, we can use it as a parent for our initial class:

```
class MyClass extends DelegatedEventTarget {

  private triggerEvent() {
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('someEvent'));
  }

}
```

This will preserve the typings and will survive the compilation down to ES5.